# Refreshing a page after certain delay in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here's my problem: i need to display a message for a while, and then reload the page.
can someone tell me how to reload a page, after certain delay?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You don't even need jQuery or HTML5 for this:

```
setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location), 60000);
```

This will wait 1 minute (60,000 milliseconds), then call the `location.reload` function, which is a built-in function to refresh the page.

Comment: Results in "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal Invocation".  See answer from Amin Jafari, it is easy to wrap this in an anonymous function and for it to be a functional solution.

Comment: Looks good, a nice solution (tighter than an anonymous function).

Answer (score 24):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload(); // you can pass true to reload function to ignore the client cache and reload from the server
},delayTime); //delayTime should be written in milliseconds e.g. 1000 which equals 1 second
```

**Update:**

One-liner using ES6:

```
setTimeout(() => window.location.reload(), delayTime);
```

Comment: I had to use window.location.reload(); but this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You may try this ***without js***, it cycles:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"/> <!-- 5 sec interval-->
<h1>Page refersh in every 5 seconds...</h1>
```

You can even navigate to a different page, visiting google home page

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;http://www.google.com"/> <!-- 5 sec delay-->
<h1>Redirecting in 5 seconds...</h1>
```

Comment: And what if the design is like, when user clicking on a button a message should display, and after displaying that message, in a delay of 5 secs the page should be reloaded..? Will this work in that context.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, OP didn't mentioned this as requirement in his post. Of course what you have said will require a different solution, possibly `window.setTimeout`.