# Asking for guideline to detect if an element in a site has changed

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have some knowledge in front end and programming in general. I searched for what I'm asking but still confused. I have a site that after some time, it make some appointments (that are exist), active. So I want to make extension(as it is the suitable idea in my head now, feel free to advice me with another one) to refresh the page every some time (1 minute or 5 for example) and detect if there are new appointment becomes available or not. I don't know what class or change they made to make it active, so maybe I'm going to check if the HTML element has changed or not.if changed, alarm maybe run.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Outside of using page reload ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400845/refreshing-a-page-after-certain-delay-in-jquery) you could use ajax to your server to get a new list of available slots. I myself have done this in PHP: You create a page with some GET parameters and have it return a JSON with the results. And you can test this first just using server calls before inserting the request into your javascript